# Capture repetitive groups separated by optional and/or

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-group

here is the generalized pattern that I am struggling with

if **condition1 and|or condition2** then **action1 and|or action2**

Condition as well as action generally has this pattern:
`situation >= 10 or situationB = off|on`

The problem is the repetitive and/or in condition/action, it could totally be absent (0 count of and/or) or as many (*).

example string:
`situation >= 10 or situationB = off and situationC = on` 
`situation = on`

Here's something I tried but need some help:

```
^\s*(\w+)\s*(=|\>=)\s*(\d+|\w+)\s*(and|or)?
```

[regex101 link](https://regex101.com/r/LWhzRT/2)

How can modify the regex so that it could group each of the conditions/actions that may or may not be separated by and/or?

Comment: What programming language are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try using the following regex pattern:

```
(.*?)(?:\s+(?:and|or)|\s*$)
```

### Demo

This matches in the first capture group all content in between possible `and/or` separators, including the final term until the end of the string.

Note that if you are using a programming language, then an easier option might be to just split on `\s*\b(?:and|or)\b\s*`, which would yield an array/collection of matching terms.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `\G` anchor to continue after the previous match.

```
(?:^|\G)(?<variable>\w+)\s*(?<operator>>?=)\s*(?<value>\w+)\s*(?:(?<conjunct>and|or) )?
```

[Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/LWhzRT/3)

Comment: I wish I could select both as answers. Thanks for your help with named groupds